# How to play a background video using angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have tried in several ways, but I couldn't find a better one. I really want to play a background video using pure Angularjs

Answer (score -1):

Hi why dont you use this

http://www.videogular.com/

Its a well documented Lib